# ReportViewer 11 Showing error message

Tags: service, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, reportviewer

I am using the Reporting Services to generate reports. I have recently upgraded my ReportViewer control from version 9 to version 11. The problem i have is that on version 11 i get an error message

`<div id="Viewer_ctl09_NonReportContent" style="height:100%;width:100%; display:none;">                                 <div style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;">                                    <!--                                       at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.MissingEndpointException.ThrowIfEndpointMissing(WebException e)&#13;&#10;   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.ValidateConnection()&#13;&#10;   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SoapReportExecutionService.GetServerVersion()&#13;&#10;   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.GetServerVersion()&#13;&#10;   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.PrintCabOperation.CreateUrl(ReportControlSession reportControlSession, ClientArchitecture clientArch, String instanceID)&#13;&#10;   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ClientPrintInfo..ctor(ReportViewer viewer)&#13;&#10;   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)-->                                  <ul>                                        <li style="display:inline;">The attempt to connect to the report server failed.  Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version.</li><ul>                                             <li style="display:inline;">The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.</li>                                        </ul>                                   </ul>                               </div>                          </div>.`

This happens when the report controller first loads, the reports work when i do some filtering. Now this happens when i have the tag ProcessingMode set to Remote. When set to Local i dont have this problem. I am using Sql Server 2005, Reporting Services 2008 R2, and ReportViewer 11.

Has anyone come across this before???? Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a post that deals with this exact issue:  [The attempt to connect to the report server failed](http://dyslexicanaboko.blogspot.com/2012/11/the-attempt-to-connect-to-report-server.html).

Comment: Cheers Ann. I went through the solution on the link provided and it helped me correct some connection issues. Also for anyone else having problems with this there is a default service url which ReportViewer 11 sets up in the properties. So if you are setting the service url from code behind make sure you set it first thing i.e onInit. Thanks again Ann.